# Python: Neural network strange and consistent output

Tags: python, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to create my first neural network. I'm trying to create a "virtual creatures" system, in which each creature has two sensors in the top of their head.
The input the network get is the distances from the two sensors to the closest food source. By the output I'm supposed to decide whether the creature is suppose to go left or right, and in what angle. The problem is, that i always get the same result (It always goes right or left). My calculations are as follow:

```
def forward(self, X):
    self.z1 = np.dot(np.insert(X, len(X), 1), self.W1)
    self.a1 = self.sigmoid(self.z1)
    self.z2 = np.dot(np.insert(self.a1, len(self.a1), 1), self.W2)
    results = self.sigmoid(self.z2)
    return results
```

I calculate the angle by:

```
    left_d = distance(sensors[0], food_pos)
    right_d = distance(sensors[1], food_pos)
    max_dis = sqrt(WIDTH**2 + HEIGHT ** 2)
    output = self.NN.forward(np.array([float(left_d) / max_dis, float(right_d) / max_dis]))
    if output[0] > output[1]:
        self.angle += (output[0] - 0.5) * np.pi
    else:
        self.angle -= (output[1] - 0.5) * np.pi
```

I've also tried the network with random inputs, and i found out that for a given NN, the output will always be (X,Y) such that X > Y or that X < Y, never randomized between the two in the same NN.

Here is some data from a run:

```
X - [ 0.78958477  0.69948212]
Z1 - [ 1.61766664  1.56767388  1.82580234]
A1 - [ 0.99890179  0.99999513  0.96766178]
Z2 - [ 1.45907443  0.92895941]
R - [ 0.9937656   0.80099741]
X - [ 0.14044444  0.60987121]
Z1 - [ 0.97104647  1.00091401  1.23983745]
A1 - [ 0.82547683  0.84196448  0.94573119]
Z2 - [ 1.28368194  0.85941254]
R - [ 0.95906503  0.75745915]
```

as you can see, R is consistant for this and for ~million measures.
Here is my weight initialization:

```
self.W1 = np.random.rand(self.inputLayerSize + 1, self.hiddenLayerSize)
self.W2 = np.random.rand(self.hiddenLayerSize + 1, self.outputLayerSize)
```

Note: I'm using genetic algorithm rather than backpropagation.
Here is the GA part:

```
def merge_guppies(screen, g1, g2):
    W11, W12 = g1.NN.get_W()
    W21, W22 = g2.NN.get_W()
    W1 = [[0] * len(W11[0])] * len(W11)
    W2 = [[0] * len(W12[0])] * len(W12)
    for k in xrange(len(W11)):
        for j in xrange(len(W11[k])):
            if uniform(0, 1) > 0.9:
                W1[k][j] = uniform(0, 1)
            elif uniform(0, 1) > 0.45:
                W1[k][j] = W11[k][j]
            else:
                W1[k][j] = W21[k][j]
    for k in xrange(len(W12)):
        for j in xrange(len(W12[k])):
            if uniform(0, 1) > 0.9:
                W2[k][j] = uniform(0, 1)
            elif uniform(0, 1) > 0.45:
                W2[k][j] = W12[k][j]
            else:
                W2[k][j] = W22[k][j]
    W1 = np.array(W1)
    W2 = np.array(W2)
    g = Guppy(screen)
    g.NN.set_W(W1, W2)
    return g
```

I doubt if the problem is here, considering it occured in other tests i've made with my NN (just giving it random inputs), but who knows... I've been searching for an answer for couple of days now and i'm pretty lost.

Any help will be appreciated. Any idea where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Where is your learning? Backpropagation? Where is the initialization for your weights? Have you printed not only some outputs but some of the intermediate results, too?

Comment: @ascenator I've added some information to my question, including all of the details you've asked about.

Comment: Could you try a centralised initialisation of your weights? Something like `np.random.rand(...) - .5`.

Comment: Also, it seems that you are computing your biases (that `np.insert` 1 in the forward function) but not adding them to the activations, are you?